# PostgreSQL, permission denied when inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

After creating a user, I used the following code to grant privileges to a user:

```
grant all privileges on schema schema_name to jesse;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema schema_name to jesse;
grant all privileges on all sequences in schema schema_name to jesse;
```

(As I side note, I have no idea what the last query means, but I ran it just in case.)

Looking at the permissions table, indeed it says the user has insert privileges:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM   information_schema.table_privileges
WHERE  grantee = 'jesse' and table_name='table_name'
```

However when the user attempts to insert, I get a permission denied on relation table_name error. It is notable that when he tries to select on the same table everything works fine.

How do I grant this user INSERT privileges?

Comment: Are you trying to insert with a `COPY` command or from somewhere outside of the database? Are you certain `jesse` is the current user trying to do the `INSERT`?

Comment: That was it, thanks. It was the wrong user.